# Webstorm Integration for KendoUI and Angular Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intellij-idea, kendo-ui, webstorm

Is there any integration for the Kendo UI Framework by Telerik for the Webstorm IDE, so the widgets will be autocompleted in the HTML?
Out of the box, Webstorm shows some custom directives for mobile Angular widgets, but only a few. 
I was thinking, as Webstorm enabled custom directive support for Angular, this should work without any plugin.
Do I have to make settings adjustments to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Kendo support is not a part of Angular plugin. WebStorm knows nothing about kendo-specific attributes. You can add all your k-* attributes to custom HTML tag attributes list in `Settings/Editor/Inspections/HTML/`, `Unknown HTML tag attribute`: attributes from this list will be shown up in completion list and not reported as not allowed

Comment: I'm fine with the attributes, but what about the directives? Shouldn't they be recognized, as KendoUI brings its' own angular directives? I mean what confuses me is this: Webstorm recognizes this one and shows autocompletion in HTML:  `<kendo-mobile-view></kendo-mobile-view>`, but does not recognize this one `<kendo-mobile-nav-bar></kendo-mobile-nav-bar>`